# Why do I get a different result when I add an assignment statement?

Tags: c

Below is my code.
Work on Debian/testing ,use gcc version 11.2.0 (Debian 11.2.0-10).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, n, m;

    printf("Input a number：");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
        //printf("%d", m%10);

    return 0;
}
```

I input 25 to n.

---

if i use

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
```

The result is 5.

---

If I use

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        printf("%d", m%10);
```

The result is 1234567890123456789012345.

---

If I use

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
    i = m%10;
    printf("%d", m%10);
```

The result is 6.

---

What is the difference between them ？

Comment: Learn what is the compound statement and what is the sub-statement of the for statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C != Python, you need to enclose all the statements into a `{}` block.

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
```

is equivalent to

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
{
    i = m%10;
}
printf("%d", i); // 25 % 10 = 5
```

and you want

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
{
    i = m%10;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not use tabs or other indentation to group statements. Each loop, such as `for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)`, includes exactly one statement. So this code:

```
    for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
            i = m%10;
            printf("%d", i);
```

is parsed as:

```
    // A loop with one statement.
    for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;

    // A separate statement.
    printf("%d", i);
```

To include multiple statements in a loop, you group them into a new *compound statement* using braces:

```
    for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
    {
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
    }
```

The code formed with `{ … }` is a single statement that is composed of any number of statements and declarations.

Answer (score 0):

To make this code snippet more readable

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
```

it may be equivalently rewritten like

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        i = m%10;
printf("%d", i);
```

So the call of printf after the for loop outputs the last value stored in the variable i when m is equal to n that is 5.

If you wanted to include the statement with the call of printf in the body of the for loop you could use the compound statement like

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
{
        i = m%10;
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

This for loop

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        printf("%d", m%10);
```

execute the statement with the call of printf in each iteration of the loop for the variable m in the range [1, n].

This code snippet

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
    i = m%10;
    printf("%d", m%10);
```

that is better again to rewrite for readability like

```
for (m = 1; m <= n; m++)
    i = m%10;
printf("%d", m%10);
```

outputs the expression m % 10 then m after the for loop is equal to n + 1.